# Why does it say that Raid 10 recovery is not supported?

Tags: raid

I have a QNAP with a 8X2TB Raid 5, that I am going to replace to a 6X2TB Raid 10 + 2 hot spares

RTFM on my hardware, I noticed something, which I don't understand, and hoped someone can enlighten me:

[Link to Documentation](http://docs.qnap.com/nas/en/index.html?raid_management.htm)

- On the Recover (RAID Recovery) section, there is a table, that says:

RAID 10 - does not support RAID Recovery - I don't understand this, and I am sure I am missing something.

- what type/kind of recovery is this about? volume? data?